# Responsive web layout on IE6 without javascript

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is it possible to create a responsive website design for IE6 without using javascript?

Comment: *Without JavaScript?* The answer is **NO**! :( You might consider to install [ChromeFrame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe/) though!

Comment: I don't have access to IE6 to test right now but this is a [responsive layout](http://designlunatic.com/projects/blucss/) that doesn't use Javascript

Comment: @JaredMcAteer, doesn't seem to work for IE7, so I can only assume it won't work for IE6, but I will find out for sure tonight.

Comment: try https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond works in 8, 7 and 6

Comment: @JaredMcAteer, tried it in IE6 and it does not work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Techniques For Gracefully Degrading Media Queries](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/10/techniques-for-gracefully-degrading-media-queries/).

They list the following ways:

1. Technique 1: Do Nothing
2. Technique 2: Conditional IE Style Sheets
3. Technique 3: Circumvent Media Query Conditions
4. Technique 4: Respond.js
5. Technique 5: CSS3-MediaQueries-js

So basically you'll be fiddling around with polyfills, javascript I know, or go for some conditional IE style sheets.

So basically: IE6 still remains a pain.

Comment: Hey XIII, resurrecting this because I could use some advice. For a mobile-first and responsive approach that also supports old IE browsers, I like options #1 and #3. However, for #3, I can't find any documentation on how to do it. The old Opera guide that Smashing Mag linked do didn't make sense to me in this context... what do you suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

without JS no way, not with IE6. This library ([click here](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)) is a polyfill for IE6 to add support for media queries etc. and will do what you need.